# On Prem IIS and Azure Application Insight

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using ASP.NET core web api which is hosted on IIS server (on prem). Configured to use Application Insight to send logs to Azure. Works fine on my machine and worked on IIS server also for some time. But it stopped working now and not able to figure out what is going on. Any help is appreciated as I am getting ready to move this app to prod. Doesn't look like it is a firewall issue as it was working okay.

Thanks

I checked all logs and not finding anything in the logs. It was working for sometime.

Here is the code in ConfigureServices()....

```
// configure appication insight telemetry 
services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
var appInsightConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights");
string instrumentationKey = appInsightConnectionString.GetValue("InstrumentationKey"); 
services.AddSingleton(); 
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(instrumentationKey);
```

No logs are sent to Azure App Insight

Answer (score 0):

Below are the possible reasons that you might have stopped seeing the data. Please check it out.

- Check the [status blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Monitor-Status/bg-p/AzureMonitorStatusBlog).
- Have you hit your monthly quota of data points? Open the
  Settings/Quota and Pricing to find out. If so, you can upgrade your
  plan, or pay for additional capacity. See the [pricing scheme](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/).

[Additional Documentation Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data#i-used-to-see-data-but-it-has-stopped).

Hope this helps.